# Reference to undefined variable surefireArgLine - unable to run a selenium file

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

i am getting Reference to undefined variable surefireArgLine  while running the selenium file through TestNg

Maven surefire plugin configuration:

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration> </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you add more detail - like what the entire error output is and what command you ran?

Comment: <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
           
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

Comment: @tummalsr - Please edit your question and add complete details on how your pom file looks like, how are you running the tests, and what is the complete console output.